# Is my sprinkler system broken?

Tags: sprinkler-system

In the past, to blow out my sprinkler system, I'd close my main in valve, hook up my compressor to a hose spigot, set the output to 40-60, open the spigot and it will charge my main line and I then go through each zone letting it blow the water out until it's just air. Then I close the valve and move to the next zone.

Now, when I do everything listed above but go to open the spigot to charge my main line, its like every zone is already open and lets air hiss out of each sprinkler head. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like a bad zone valve.

Answer (score 0):

The zone valves need water pressure to close. Once you removed the pressure from the main source the valves couldn't stay closed. Your air will escape through all the valves and the heads each services.

Comment: How do i fix it? Ive done this since i put thr system in 18 years ago and its not until this year it started having problems